# Combine different OData paths for bindings in a single view

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Best to explain my question with an example:
The view:

```
<navContainer>
<page id="first">
<label text="{name}"/>
</page>
<page id="second">
<label text="{car}"/>
</page>
</navContainer>
```

The model is an OData service. For the 'first' page I want to use the entity '/EmployeeSet(0)' and for the 'second' page I want to use the entity '/CarSet(0)'.

So far I came up with this technique but it's not working for me:

```
this.byId("first").bindElement("/EmployeeSet(0)");
this.byId("second").bindElement("/CarSet(0)");
```

What's the correct way to set the binding for each page? 
Can this still work with a single model and so I'm not required to reference a named model in the view like 'text="{secondModel>car}"'?

---

Update:
The auto complete list in the WebIDE is not showing "binding", but that's what I needed. It works.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, I guess there is an issue somewhere else. Did you also check if the server returns data? What do you expect to see from the view you listed above?

Anyway, here is a [little jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/qunisukako/edit?html,output) I just sketched up for you (see below). binsElement() is actually the same binding="" in the view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">

                <Panel id="panel1" binding="{/Customers('ALFKI')}">
                  <Text text="{CompanyName}"/>
                </Panel>

                <Panel id="panel2" binding="{/Customers('ANATR')}">
                  <Text text="{CompanyName}"/>
                </Panel>                

            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
                ], function (Controller, ODataModel) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () {
                            this.getView().setModel(
                                new ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", {
                                    json : true,
                                    useBatch : false
                                })
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is another [jsbin example using NavContainer & Pages](https://jsbin.com/vuloxucuku/edit?html,output) (based on the NavContainer example from the Explored App).
And this [jsbin example is the same but uses bindElement()](https://jsbin.com/sosuvosogi/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thanks for your working example Nabi. I'm trying to set the binding on the  sap.m.page (I have different pages in a navcontainer), but the "binding=" attribute for a <Page> doesn't seem to exist? I only see "bindingContexts".

Comment: bindElement() exists, so this means you can also use binding="" in the view. It's the same.

Comment: well, I guess the WebIDE could be improved here and there... ;-) Anyway, I have added 2 new jsbins for.